# Can't create a relocatable pe file with cl that generates a ".reloc" section

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, portable-executable, osdev

that's my first question on stack overflow. I'm writing a kernel, and I'm looking for running drivers. The kernel can run some simple user applications in pe32+ format that loads on a fixed virtual address, however i need to load drivers in kernel space and that needs a compatible relocatable image.

I can read the dll import table, the subsystem and section headers of the driver image i created using msvc cl. But it seems to not have a ".reloc" section even though i specified in linker options /DYNAMICBASE and /FIXED:NO. The dll i created for the driver api seems to have the same problem and when i read hexadecimal output in HexDecoder. there is no reloc section. I've also seen the data directories and the relocation base entry is clear.

**Here is the compiling options for the driver:**

```
cl /I inc /I ../../libc/inc /I ../../libc/drv/inc /Fo:obj/x86_64/ /Fe:osdwm.sys src/*.c "../gdk.lib" /link /machine:x64 /subsystem:native /fixed:no /dynamicbase 
copy /b osdwm.sys "../../kernel/iso/os/system"
```

**Here is for the dll driver kit**

```
 cl src/*.c /dll /dynamicbase  /I ../inc /I ../drv/inc /Fe:gdk.dll /link /dll /fixed:no /dynamicbase /subsystem:native /machine:x64

 copy /b gdk.dll "../../kernel/iso/os/system"
 copy /b gdk.lib "../../drivers/gdk.lib"
```

So i created some symbols like this. the loader relocated them and it worked. But how can i make every function like a symbol because this is a driver and its painful to make that declaration for every symbol.

```
extern void _cli();
extern void _hlt();
extern void __stdcall movrbx(UINT64 value);

void (*foofi)() = _hlt;
void (*foo)() = _cli;
GDKSTATUS GDKENTRY DriverEntry(DRIVER_HEADER* DriverHeader, LPCWSTR SystemPath)
{
    foo();
    foofi();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The section is not generated if you don't have relocatable symbols (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601914/507028 )

Answer (score 0):

After hard searching and reading the PE specification in these 2 days, I was able to load the driver and link it to the DLL (this operation is called "delay-loading"). And I want to share with you some of what I've found.

First, the driver and any application compiled with MSVC has "dynamic base" enabled by default, which enables ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization).

Let's take function A, function B (Both in ".text" section) and int C in ".data" section, when linking the linker calculates the difference in virtual address between these symbols. Which makes the executable being able to load at any address in memory without restricting a fixed base address or relocating every function which can take alot of space in the executable image.

Take this example:

```
 0x1000 - Function A
 
 0x1100 - Function B
          callq $ - 0x100 # Current Address - 0x100 which is address of Function A

 mov eax, $ + 0x1F00 # int C

 0x3000 - int C = 123
```

But when declaring a symbol reference like :

```
int (*AddressOfA)() = A;
```

If /FIXED is enabled then the result will be a fixed virtual address from the Image Base. But if /FIXED:NO is specified. The linker can't know the address where the image will be loaded since it is a dynamic based image, the linker will create a symbol reference in the ".reloc" section which will be processed by OS at load time and will change its value to be relative to the address where the image has been loaded.